# PATH Variable is not updating in Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

First of all, thank you for any suggestions. After some tweaks of the routine the code looks like this:

```
REM ========================================================================
REM Parses out Path entries
REM ======================================================================= 
    SETLOCAL
    SET TEMPPATH="%PATH%"
    SET NEWPATH =""
    CALL :parse %TEMPPATH%
    GOTO :NEXT

:PARSE
    SET list=%1
    SET list=%list:"=%
    FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a IN ("%list%") DO (
        REM ECHO A: %%a
        REM ECHO B: %%b
        IF NOT "%%a"=="%VAR_JAVA_HOME%" CALL :SUB "%%a"
        IF NOT "%%b"=="" CALL :PARSE "%%b"   
    )
    EXIT /b

:SUB
    ECHO Passed into subroutine: %1
    IF DEFINED NEWPATH IF "%NEWPATH%" == "" (
        SET NEWPATH=%1;
        ECHO IN SUB: %NEWPATH%
    )
    IF DEFINED NEWPATH IF "%NEWPATH:~0,1%, %1" == "" (
        SET NEWPATH=%NEWPATH%;%1
        ECHO Updated NEWPATH: %NEWPATH%
    )
    REM ECHO New path variable: %NEWPATH% 
    EXIT /b

:NEXT
    ECHO New path variable: %NEWPATH% 
    ECHO Removed Java entries from the path...
    ENDLOCAL
```

The routine is compiling and running. The individual entries in the path are being parsed out correctly and passed into the subroutine. However, the new path is not being created or is it being updated.

```
Passed into subroutine: "C:\Windows\system32"
Passed into subroutine: "C:\Windows"
Passed into subroutine: "C:\Windows\System32\Wbem"
Passed into subroutine: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"
New path variable:<nothing here>
```

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Russ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never entering the branches with `if defined NEWPATH` because there is no variable named `NEWPATH`. You have a superfluous space in the following line:

```
SET NEWPATH =""
```

So the variable name is actually `NEWPATH`  (including a space at the end).

Comment: I've been bitten by that one. It's one of the most exasperating quirks of the Windows command line.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I'll introduce you to a secret then: That exact same quirk also exists in the Unix command line :-)

Comment: Thank you Now I have: IF NOT DEFINED NEWPATH IF "%NEWPATH%"=="" ( SET NEWPATH=%1; ECHO IN SUB: %NEWPATH% ) My error has changed to:  Passed into subroutine: C:\Windows\system32 C:\Windows\system32"=="" ( was unexpected at this time.